# Dropdown menu mobile error

Tags: html, menu, dropdown

I have problem with my dropdown menu. This not work on mobile device.

```
<div class="header-col header-col-fluid">
    <nav class="mega-menu" id="main_mega_menu">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="nav-menu menu-primary-navigation">
            <li id="nav-menu-item-6310" class="mega-menu-item nav-item menu-item-depth-0"><a href="" class="menu-link main-menu-link"><span class="item-title">Item1</span></a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-6239" class="mega-menu-item nav-item menu-item-depth-0"><a href=""  class="menu-link main-menu-link"><span class="item-title">Item2</span></a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-6124" class="mega-menu-item nav-item menu-item-depth-0"><a href=""  class="menu-link main-menu-link"><span class="item-title">Item3</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-language menu-item-language-current">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false"><img class="iclflag" src="falg1.png" width="18" height="12" alt="" title="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-language menu-item-language-current">
                <a href="en/index.htm" ><img class="iclflag" src="flag.png" width="18" height="12" alt="" title="" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="dl-menuwrapper">
        <a href="#" class="dl-trigger icon-mobile-menu">Menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? How should it work? Whats the exact problem?

Comment: https://scr.hu/8evy4R

Comment: this should show menu like on bootstrap but not work :(